# mysql on localhost (MAMP) access data with Applescript: connection refused

Tags: php, mysqli, applescript, mamp

I've got an Applescript that calls a php script which retrieves some data from local MySQL database and returns it back to applescript.

Everything works fine when I start the MAMP App normally.

But... I wanted to avoid opening additional application window (MAMP) and also skip on entering my user password each time it starts. I found [this little workaround](http://www.46palermo.com/blog/run-mamp-without-password-easy-way/).

Summarising:

I'm starting the servers from Applescript as follows

```
do shell script "/Applications/MAMP/bin/startApache.sh &" password...
do shell script "/Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh > /dev/null 2>&1"
```

Servers are running and I'm able to browse and edit dbs in MyAdmin.

My simple php script to retrieve data from MySQL db works fine from command line

```
$ php /cmp/get-project-details.php
```

But it won't work from Applescript :(

```
set mrProjDetailsJson to do shell script "php " & ABSPATH & "/cmp/get-project-details.php"
```

throwing: *Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in...*

What I'm missing here?

Comment: Are there settings in the Terminal Shell Environment when you run `php /cmp/get-project-details.php` that are not in the Shell Environment passed to `do shell script` that might be an issue? Compare the output of `do shell script "set"` to `set` executed in Terminal.

Comment: The output is quite different, the first difference is that in Applescript `BASH=/bin/sh` and in Terminal `BASH=/bin/bash`. Would it be a good idea to use bash from Applescript and how? Also I wonder why all is fine with MAMP started 'normally'.